# Create matrix from mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert mongodb documents into matrix format

for e.g.

for **this input**

```
[
  {
    username: "user1",
    result: [
      {
        subId: "sub1",
        marks: 90
      },
      {
        subId: "sub4",
        marks: 92
      },
      {
        subId: "sub3",
        marks: 73
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    username: "user3",
    result: [
      {
        subId: "sub3",
        marks: 87
      },
      {
        subId: "sub5",
        marks: 91
      },
      {
        subId: "sub2",
        marks: 88
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**output should be like this**

```
        sub1  |  sub2  |  sub3  |  sub4  |  sub5  | 
======|=======|========|========|========|========|
user1 |  90   |        |    73  |        |        |      
user2 |       |        |        |        |        |      
user3 |       |   88   |    87  |        |   91   |
```

I tried to approach this problem by mongodb aggregate, pandas and numpy library but couldn't get the desired output.

Can you please suggest me some other way to make it work.

Comment: Is ``sub5`` always last or there may also be ``sub6``?

Comment: Ids assigned to subjects and users are incremented by 1, so the max subid can only be the subId which is stored in any user's result object. So it depends but In this case it is sub5. Same rule applies to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert each document to flat document(not nested).

So first record will be this:

```
{'user': 'user1', 'sub1': 90, 'sub4': 92, 'sub3': 73}
```

Now you can use pandas to create from a dict.

This is full code:

```
doc_list = [
    {
        'username': "user1",
        'result': [
            {
                'subId': "sub1",
                'marks': 90
            },
            {
                'subId': "sub4",
                'marks': 92
            },
            {
                'subId': "sub3",
                'marks': 73
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'username': "user3",
        'result': [
            {
                'subId': "sub3",
                'marks': 87
            },
            {
                'subId': "sub5",
                'marks': 91
            },
            {
                'subId': "sub2",
                'marks': 88
            }
        ]
    }
]

pandas_list = []
for doc in doc_list:
    line = {'user': doc['username']}

    for sub_mark in doc['result']:
        line[sub_mark['subId']] = sub_mark['marks']

    pandas_list.append(line)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(pandas_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$result" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$username",
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$result.subId", "v": "$result.marks" }}
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }}},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$data" }}
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "user1": {
      "sub1": 90,
      "sub3": 73,
      "sub4": 92
    },
    "user3": {
      "sub2": 88,
      "sub3": 87,
      "sub5": 91
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "arr": { 
            $reduce: {
                input: {
                    $map: {
                        "input": "$result",
                        "as": "this",
                        "in": {
                            $let: {
                                "vars": {
                                    "tmp": { $objectToArray: "$$this" }
                                },
                                "in": {
                                    $arrayToObject: [[
                                        {
                                            k: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$tmp.v", 0 ] },
                                            v: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$tmp.v", 1 ] }
                                        }
                                    ]]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "initialValue": { "_id": "$_id" },
                "in": { $mergeObjects: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        "newRoot": "$arr"
    }
})
```

The result would be:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe443ef68f12cf65d17b14"),
    "sub1" : 90,
    "sub4" : 92,
    "sub3" : 73
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe443ef68f12cf65d17b16"),
    "sub3" : 87,
    "sub5" : 91,
    "sub2" : 88
}
```